# How to sum multiple fields of a list of objects using stream in java

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I'm trying to get the sums of two fields from a Model class. and return it using using a pojo but kept getting syntax errors. What I am trying to achieve is similar to the highest voted answer in This: [Summing multiple different fields in a list of objects using the streams api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039318/summing-multiple-different-fields-in-a-list-of-objects-using-the-streams-api) but I got syntax error. Here is my model:

```
public class BranchAccount {


    @NotNull(message = "Account balance is required")
    private Double accountBalance;

    @NotNull(message = "Profit is required")
    private Double profit;


    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastUpdated;
}
```

My Pojo:

```
public class ProfitBalanceDto {

   private Double accountBalance;

   private Double profit;

}
```

My code to get sum of accountBalance and profit from BranchAccount:

```
public ProfitBalanceDto getAllBranchAccount() {
    List<BranchAccount> branchAccounts = branchAccountRepository.findAll();
            branchAccounts.stream()
            .reduce(new ProfitBalanceDto(0.0, 0.0), (branchAccount1, branchAccount2) -> {
                return new ProfitBalanceDto(
                        branchAccount1.getAccountBalance() + branchAccount2.getAccountBalance(),
                        branchAccount1.getProfit() + branchAccount2.getProfit());
            });

return null;
}
```

My errors:
[image]

Please am I doing wrong? 
PS: I want to use stream for this.

Comment: What does the red-lined error say?

Comment: You are streaming over instances of `BranchAccount`. You can’t reduce them to a `ProfitBalanceDto` without a conversion, either using the [three arg `reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) or perform a [`map` step](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) before `reduce`.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor it says Bad return type in lambda expression.

Comment: @Holger thank you for your correction, the question has been answered. However I'd like to see a similar code with the three arg reduce you mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Holger mentioned in his comment, you can map to `ProfitBalanceDto` before reducing

```
public ProfitBalanceDto getAllBranchAccount2() {
    List<BranchAccount> branchAccounts = branchAccountRepository.findAll();
    return branchAccounts.stream()
                         .map(acc -> new ProfitBalanceDto(acc.getAccountBalance(), acc.getProfit()))
                         .reduce(new ProfitBalanceDto(0.0, 0.0),
                                 (prof1, prof2) -> new ProfitBalanceDto(prof1.getAccountBalance()+ prof2.getAccountBalance(),
                                                                        prof1.getProfit() + prof2.getProfit()));
}
```

If you are using Java 12 or higher using the teeing collector might be a better option

```
public ProfitBalanceDto getAllBranchAccount() {
    List<BranchAccount> branchAccounts = branchAccountRepository.findAll();
    return branchAccounts.stream()
                         .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                                 Collectors.summingDouble(BranchAccount::getAccountBalance),
                                 Collectors.summingDouble(BranchAccount::getProfit),
                                 ProfitBalanceDto::new));
}
```